# Ubuntu Netboot CD Images ever go down?

Tags: ubuntu, netboot

I just started using netboot for our organization for network deployment of the OS, but I was asked a question in regards to reliability and availability of using netboot. This question might sound silly, but does netboot ever have any down time or have outages to the point it becomes unavailable?

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/

Answer (score 0):

In the world of technology, we fully expect that there is some downtime.  Nobody guarantees 100% uptime, so you should ideally be prepared to deal with some downtime at some point.  This is especially true if you are not paying for the service.

There are two possible network connections you need to consider.  First, the downloading of the Ubuntu netboot images that you use to boot, and second, the package mirrors that you have to use.  The first can be solved by downloading the materials and hosting it on your own TFTP or equivalent server.  Then you're in control of the reliability of the bootable materials.

You also have to consider the package mirrors that are required for installation.  These are typically a little more resilient, since they tend to be located in a variety of places.  You may not wish to worry about this situation, since it seems less likely to happen, and just deal with an outage if it occurs.  You could also set up a caching proxy, which may improve both resilience and speed, especially if you are deploying many machines at once.

Ultimately, the amount of risk you're willing to take for an outage depends on you and your company.  I would expect outages here to be relatively infrequent, so if your environment is not time sensitive or safety critical, investing heavily in a more robust architecture may not be important.  However, if people's lives or livelihoods depend on being able to deploy infrastructure immediately, a backup plan might be prudent.